# Is there an automatically scrolling, time-delayed Unix pager command?

Tags: unix, less, pager

I'd like to view output of big commands slowed down, like a slideshow with e.g. automatic, 500ms delay between each scroll. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution using `bash`:

```
function scroll
{
    while read -r ; do echo "$REPLY" ; sleep ${1:-0.5} ; done
}
```

## Usage

```
long_command | scroll [delay]
```

`delay` is optional and defaults to `0.5`.

Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: I don't know why my edit get rejected, but be warned that `echo /** ` in your output of long_command (e.g. `cat` a file) will stuck and flood your terminal session if you don't put double quotes on `"$REPLY"`.

Comment: @林果皞 approved and removed the warning, thanks. I should have added the quotes in the first place.

Comment: ... I added the warning just because system doesn't allow edit only 2 characters.

Answer (score 4):

If you can live with 1s resolution, you could do `tail -n +0 -f -s <seconds>`.

Comment: The output from `long_command` is possibly generated in less than a second so there's no point in polling for its completeness every `<interval>` and indeed doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `vim` with an appropriate mapping to achieve this:

```
vim -c 'map <S-f20> L:redraw<cr>:sleep 500m<cr><C-d><S-f20>' -c 'execute "normal \<S-f20>"' -
```

<kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> scrolls half a page at a time, replace with <kbd>10j</kbd> to scroll 10 lines at a time.